# centos firewall-cmd block the awk ips using a script

Tags: awk, centos

There are many awk attacks to my server. I have tried to block them , but too much of them .
is there a way to block them one time?

**I use this command :**

```
netstat -an|awk -F: '{print $2}'|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr|head
```

show the result

```
[root@local ~]# netstat -an|awk -F: '{print $2}'|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr|head
   1080 80      107.189.8.33
    864 80      185.129.61.5
    485 80      23.154.177.11
    386 80      183.245.24.27
    318 80      185.243.218.32
    309 80      185.220.101.2
    276 80      61.153.251.150
    259 80        59.148.106.164
    235 80      185.175.119.113
```

**And after list a ip , I will find the connection ips to 80 port more than 100 ones . and block them .**

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address="107.189.8.0/24" drop'
```

Anyway to make a .sh file , to find out the awk ips which more than 200 connections , and add them to the droplist of the firewall?

in this case , need to exclude 127.0.0.1 and our own ips .

hope anyone can help thanks.

**I have tried to output the ips with problem using this code .**

```
netstat -an|awk -F: '{print $2}'|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr|head > ccips.txt
```

**after this , I use :**

```
awk '{sub("IP:", "", $3); print $3}' /root/ccips.txt | xargs -n1 -I{} firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address={} drop'
```

**this can block all the ips with attack .**

I just don't know how to import this to a .sh , which can be do this in one command .

Comment: Could you please post samples of expected output and output of `netstat` command to make your question more clear, thank you.

Comment: I used `awk '{sub("IP:", "", $3); print $3}' /root/ccips.txt | xargs -n1 -I{} firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address={} drop'` . to block the ips , and use : `netstat -an|awk -F: '{print $2}'|sort|uniq -c|sort -nr|head > ccips.txt` to get the ips.

Comment: but don't know how to import this to a .sh .

Comment: What does `There are many awk attacks to my server` mean? awk doesn't attack anything, it's just a text processing tool. Are you just saying you want to block IP addresses connecting to port 80 that aren't your local IP addresses? If so please [edit] your question to show the output of `netstat -an` plus a set of IP addresses you do not want blocked.

Comment: You're using `head` which will only print the first 10 IPs output by the preceding pipeline. Is that deliberate as you only want to block 10 IP addresses for some reason or is it a bug and you actually want to block all IP addresses connecting to port 80 that aren't in your local list?

Comment: The `sub("IP:", "", $3)` in your final awk script seems to be redundant as the IP addresses you show in the output of your first script don't have the string `IP:` in them.

Comment: yes , i used head means list the top 10  connection which is not normal . and hope to block them , this is only will be used when the website is been attacked . the normal time will not be used. thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0):

I THINK what you're trying to do is create a file like this of IPs you don't want to block:

```
$ cat allowedIPs
127.0.0.1
whatever...
```

and then have a script like this to block all IPs not in that file connecting to port 80 (untested and guessing at what the `netstat -an` output looks like by reading your code):

```
$ cat blockIPs
#!/usr/bin/env bash

netstat -an |
awk -F: '
    NR == FNR {
        allowedIPs[$1]
        next
    }
    {
        split($2,portIP," ")
        port = portIP[1]
        ip = portIP[2]
    }
    (port == 80) && !(ip in allowedIPs) && !seen[ip]++ {
        print ip
    }
' allowedIPs - |
xargs -n1 -I{} firewall-cmd --permanent --add-rich-rule='rule family=ipv4 source address={} drop'
```